# WPF C#: Show new mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two wpf projects: A launcher and the program. 
I've added the existing program project to the solution and given a reference to it.

```
using EarthViewerWPF;
```

Then created a new instance of it within the partial class.

```
EarthViewerWPF.MainWindow newWindow = new EarthViewerWPF.MainWindow();
```

And finally show it in the login click event

```
if (isLoginSuccess == true)                
    newWindow.Show();
```

This should surely work right? However i get the error:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '30' and line position '30'.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

StackOverflow be a hero once again please !

Thanks

Comment: what's on line 30, position 30 in your XAML?

Comment: Hi HighCore. On like 30 of the XAML is a  comment saying: 
<!-- Defines the register UI -->
The error does say line 30, space 30 in the Baml2006 class though doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to make this work so instead added a new window to my launcher project and used the following code to show the new window.

```
MainWindow eViewer = new MainWindow();

if (isLoginSuccess == true)
            {
                this.Hide();
                eViewer.Show();    
            }
```